# Create numpy array of stacked raster image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I'm trying to read a stacked raster image as a numpy array. Actually I'd like to read all bands. But when I check array dimension, there is anything just 0. Please tell me why? and what should I do for this?

```
>>> import numpy, gdal, gdalconst, os, pandas
>>> os.chdir(r'N:\PhenologyMOD09\ImagesUsed\Condition\ndvi\Filter_tiff')
>>> gdal.AllRegister()
>>> inRas = gdal.Open("2000_allbands.tif", gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
>>> myarray = numpy.array([gdal.Open("2000_allbands.tif", gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly).ReadAsArray()
                for name, descr in inRas.GetSubDatasets()])

>>> myarray.shape
(0,)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I may, I think that this is a Python related question, not a statistical one. So you should post it on the correct Stackexchange portal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what you want to do:

```
from osgeo import gdal
inRas = gdal.Open("2000_allbands.tif")
myarray = inRas.ReadAsArray()
print(myarray.shape)  # (num_bands, y_size, x_size)
```

Comment: myarray calculation gives me following error. 
 "File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    myarray = inRas.ReadAsArray()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 769, in ReadAsArray
    return gdalnumeric.DatasetReadAsArray( self, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, buf_obj )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 231, in DatasetReadAsArray
    xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 276, in BandReadAsArray
    ar = numpy.empty([buf_ysize,buf_xsize], dtype = typecode)
MemoryError"

Comment: Sounds like you may have ran out of memory. How many bands, rows and columns? How much RAM do you have, and is this a 64-bit version of Python?

Comment: Image size is 12628 X 4144 X 30. My computer has 3.5 GB of RAM. Python version of 32-bit.

Comment: If the band type is Byte, then this is about 1.5 GB. If any other type, such as integer or float, then it will be too large to open in memory unless you have more ram and a 64-bit version. You can only examine this in parts, using either a windowed read (complicated) or read only a few bands at once (much easier).